# Get value of a specific column of a row without primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is purely out of curiosity.

```
create table test (ename varchar(50))
insert into test values ('abcd')
insert into test values ('pqrs')
insert into test values ('lmno')
insert into test values ('xxxx')
insert into test values ('tops')
```

I want the value of 3rd row from this table in a variable. i.e **"lmno"**

If I do this :

```
Declare @value varchar(50)
Select @value = ename from 
(
 select Row_number() over(order by ename) Rowno, * from test 
) X where Rowno=3

print @value
```

I will get pqrs.

I cannot use this:

```
Declare @value varchar(50)
Select @value = ename from 
(
 select Row_number() over(order by 1) Rowno, * from test 
) X where Rowno=3
```

because

> Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause
>   expressions.

Any options?

**EDIT :** 
If I query it as

```
Select * from test
```

I do get records in the order in which they were inserted. That means somewhere there is a record as to how they were inserted. I just want to capture this sequence.

Comment: The only way to get the "3rd" row is if you have another column to order your results. There is no "natural" order on a table

Comment: If you do not specify an order then you can't rely on any order

Comment: In this case, my order is the order in which i inserted those rows..

Comment: "That means somewhere there is a record as to how they were inserted", that's false, it just means that at this time it returned the rows that way, there is no "record" of how they were inserted if you don't create a column to hold that value

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try:

```
create table #test (ename varchar(50))
insert into #test values ('abcd')
insert into #test values ('pqrs')
insert into #test values ('lmno')
insert into #test values ('xxxx')
insert into #test values ('tops')

CREATE TABLE #Temp(RowID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), ename VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #temp(ename)
SELECT ename from #test

SELECT T2.*
FROM #temp T1
JOIN #test T2 ON T1.ename = T2.ename
WHERE T1.RowID = 3
```

Comment: Well, look at that, it works after you create another column with the order in which the rows are inserted. Anyway, beware that an identity value of 3 doesn't always mean that it's the 3rd row

Comment: Or, more accurately, it's the 3rd row of an arbitrarily ordered record set, which may or may not be 'pqrs' depending on a hundred different things you have no control over.

Comment: This won't necessarily work if you're just after "the third thing".  Your original question seemed to be asking about the syntax of how to specify the column(s) with which to order.  Now it seems more about the order itself. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

You are making a very very poor assumption about RDBMS's. The order that a RDBMS stores records, or they order they are written to the table is 100% absolutely inconsequential. It means nothing. It's arbitrary and you can't rely on it.

You will need to either add a new column to be the 'order' that you desire, or you will have to better define why you want `pqrs` in your recordset since `3rd record` is meaningless in this sense.

**To your edit:** There is no record of the order which the records were inserted. There is an order by which the records are returned to the record set, and that they naturally lay in the DB's structure underneath, but it is arbitrary. The reason you get them back in the order in which they were written is because you have a tiny little table on a RDBMS that stores data in a single spot. This fails as soon as you scale your architecture up. You can not and should never ever rely on the order that your RDBMS retrieves records.

Comment: He's not asking about the "natural order" which is as you say, not a thing.  He's just asking why you cannot say "order by 1" in a window while you can do that in a normal select/order by.  Personally I'd never use that form but I suppose it's there for a reason.  The answer to the question appears to be "because you can't"

Comment: @LoztInSpace, that seems like a part of the question "Why can't I ORDER BY 1" but the underlying assumption from OP is that there is a natural order on which they can rely. Which is a bad assumption. It's not only not true, it's particularly ruinous to any application built on top of it.

Comment: No it's not an underlying assumption about natural order.  I can SELECT * from Table ORDER BY 1 and get a very real, repeatable result.  It means ORDER BY [whatever column 1 is].  Same as SELECT a,b,c from Table ORDER BY a.  It's the same.

Comment: So what if it's the same. That's not the point. The point is, that relying on the arbitrary ordering that your RDBMS returns a record set is crazy-bananas insane. Just because it happened to match your expectations today doesn't mean that it will tomorrow. This isn't excel or a CSV file.

Comment: The edit shows your comments were right and my interpretation was wrong.  I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it step by step.

```
select ename from test order by ename;
```

This orders by ename.

```
select ename from test order by 1;
```

Here 1 is an alias for the 1st element in your select clause, which is ename. So you order by ename again.

```
select Row_number() over(order by ename) Rowno, * from test
```

The row_number function works on records ordered by ename.

```
select Row_number() over(order by 1) Rowno, * from test
```

What is 1 supposed to mean here? We are inside an over clause and there is no first element the 1 could refer to. So it is not allowed to use a number here (it would only be confusing, as it could only mean a literal 1 for every record which doesn't order anything).

As to "I do get records in the order in which they were inserted. That means somewhere there is a record as to how they were inserted. I just want to capture this sequence.": No, that isn't the case. Right now you happen to get the records in the order they were inserted, but this is in no way guaranteed. The only way to guarantee an order is to have fields to represent the desired order and use them in ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
create table test (ename varchar(50))
insert into test values ('abcd')
insert into test values ('pqrs')
insert into test values ('lmno')
insert into test values ('xxxx')
insert into test values ('tops')

SELECT  *FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by HH) AS RNO,ename FROM (SELECT  ENAME,'' AS HH FROM test) T)T1
WHERE RNO=3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) ID FROM test
)
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   ID = 3
```

Comment: Yes, this also works, and it's also a terrible idea. The only useful thing to come out of this exercise is to find the ordering by which your RDBMS retrieves records... which I gather is not OP's intentions.

Comment: I understand that Question is not valid. But someone need solution and want to apply immediately because already have this structure. Solution first and explanation later